# C++ avoiding typename ClassName::template MethodName

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following code:

```
template <class T>
struct Base{
   typename<class Val>
   void do_it{
     ...
   }
}

struct Concrete: Base<Data>{      
  void test(){
    ...
    do_it<Val>();      // It is ok with concrete class implementation
  }
}
```

Everything is fine.
But if I need to template my Concrete:

```
template<class T = Base<Data> >
struct Concrete: T {
  typename<class Val>
  void test(){
    ...
    // And now, I have to write "template Concrete: typename"  
    //each time when I want to call some function from parent class
    typename Concrete:: template do_it<Val>();
  }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9fea02d64263042

I understand why (because compiler may not sure at the compile moment, what a heck is that do_it), but the question is:

Is there any workaround for this? I mean not to write each time *typename Concrete: template*. At first, I tried macro

```
#define t(Class) typename Class::template
```

Than I just "forward" functions from the parent class. Write "do_it" function in Concrete, which call

```
 struct Concrete: T {
   ...
 typename<class Val>
 void do_it(){
     typename Concrete:: template do_it<Val>();
 }
   ...
 }
```

Is there some more "right" way to do this?

Comment: It's not that the "compiler isn't sure". It's because the language says so.

Comment: @Kerek SB So, there is some compiler specific keys that allow not to write "typename template"? I mean, if compiler know that. And I have to write that, only because standart says so.

Comment: You write `typename Concrete::template do_it<Val>` if `do_it` is a typename. Your `do_it` is _not_ a typename. The definition as written would not compile.

Comment: @JanHudec Look at live example http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9fea02d64263042

Comment: @tower120 It is not a valid example, because your template class isn't instantiated in it.

Comment: And if you did instantiate it, it would _not_ compile, because `do_it` is _not_ a typename, so you should _not_ have the `typename` qualification. You still need the `template` qualification though.

Comment: Proof: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/942b053f33fb0790

Comment: Note that the problem disappears completely as soon as the template parameter can be derived from an argument, i.e. if you have `template <class Val> do_it(const Val& value);`

Comment: Proof for that: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/88a4f244d4f50fdf ;)